# UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I am getting this error while running tomcat server

> The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform]
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand? Also, you might want to use a version of tomcat that is not severely outdated...